# How can i save data of the current logged in user in an array in Angular

Tags: angular

In the component Template, we can use "*ngIf="user$ | async as user"", to access all the data stored in the user... Please i need to access all of those data in the component.ts file and save them to an array, variable , I need to attach them to a js config file going to an API....
Is it possible to use the async pipe to access them in the ts file?

```js
 var gameConfig = {
      gameServer: "${server}",
      gameCode: "${gameCode}",
      apiKey: "${api}",
      username: "${username}",
      sessionKey: "${sessionID}",
      languageCode: "${language}",
      currencyCode: "${CurrencyCode}",
```

I have all those stored parameters stored in the current user profile and i can call the current logged in user as user$ = this.usersService.currentUserProfile$;.... just want a way to tap into the user$ and access all of those data.

Answer (score 0):

You already answered the question. You have to **tap** into the values of the `user$` in the TypeScript file. There is an RxJS operator just named [tap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap).

tap operator is:

> Used to perform side-effects for notifications from the source
> observable

Since `user$` is an observable you can subscribe to it (or use the tap) and map the values to your config. To use tap you have to wrap it inside a pipe(). You will need to do something like this in your `ngOnInit(){}`

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.user$.pipe(tap((response)=> console.log(response)))
}
```

PS: next time please provide more context to help people help you. Also do not forget to unsubscribe from this observable to avoid memory leak

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bro, how can i then create variables with the response? for example? for example 
const server = ???
const  gameCode = ???
const api = ??? 

and all that.... please help me out Am a newbie

Answer (score -1):

You have got the `Observable` in your `.ts` file; that is `user$`, where you can `subscribe` to, and get the result like this

```
user$.subscribe((res) => {
  console.log(res);
)};
```

Whereas `async` is a pipe you use in your `.html`

**Note**: If you are going to subscribe anyway to this `Observable`, then there's no need to use the `async` pipe in your `.html`, because you would probably want to assign the response of your subscription to a local instance `user` for example, sample code for this use case would be like this:

```
user$.subscribe((res) => {
  console.log(res);
  this.user = res;
)};
```

**Tip**: Always use `ngOnDestroy()` life cycle hook to `unsubscribe()` your `Observable` in your `.ts` file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bro, how can i then create variables with the response? for example? for example 
const server = ???
const  gameCode = ???
const api = ??? 

and all that.... please help me out Am a newbie